# Swift: getting origin coordinates of UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, constraints

I have the following UIViewController which contains a UIScrollView and its constraints:

[image]

1) left, right, top distances from UIViewController are 5

2) bottom distance from UIViewController is 80

3) the distances between each button and UIScrollView are 10

Moreover the constraints of the UIImageView are set so that its size is the same of UIScrollView (they're all 0)

Anyway, if at runtime in `viewDidAppear()` method I perform:

```
print("scroll: \(self.scrollView.contentOffset)")
print("image: \(self.imageView.frame.origin)")
```

I get

```
scroll: (0.0, 0.0)
image: (0.0, 0.0)
```

why this? They should not be positioned at the origin!!

Comment: First the contentOffset does not represent the position of the UIScrollview in it's super view. Does the views are at the right place when you launch the app? You can put a background color to see where your views are.

Comment: Ok, someone wrote in a post here that contentOffset was the origin of scrollView. Yes, both the view are at the right position when I launch the app (I have tested it with background color as you said) but the origin of the UIImageView is not really set. why does it show (0.0, 0.0)? I need to know the origin because I must move some pins over the imageView...

Comment: A view's frame's origin is the location in it's superview. Your image view is at (0, 0) within the scroll view (like you said in your initial post). The content offset of the scroll view is also (0, 0) which means that the scroll view is scrolled fully to the top. -- contentOffset and origin being the same for scroll views is the relation between `scrollView.contentOffset` and **`scrollView.bounds.origin`** which should always be the same. -- What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: thanks...so, how can I get the origin coordinates of the uiimageview? how can I set the limits by which the pins can move upon the uiimageview?

Comment: self.imageView.frame.origin will give you the origin of your image view. The problem here may be that you print these value before the layout of the super view. Try to add a button and print these values in this button actions.

Comment: To get the scrollview origin do : self.scrollview.frame.origin.